# sql create pivot chart + rows to columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot

done some research on this but haven't managed to find an example that works for me.

I have a table, image shown below, fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/20639)

[image]

what I want to do is convert the rows into columns. I read un on pivots but am lost a little.

I want my output to be:

[image]

using sql, how can I achieve this.

Does this have to be achieved with variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to get the result.  If you have a known number of values, then you can hard-code the query similar to the following:

```
select type, color,
  [1], [1.5], [2], [3], [4]
from
(
  select type, color, length, price
  from items
) d
pivot
(
  max(price)
  for length in ([1], [1.5], [2], [3], [4])
) piv
order by type;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/20639/14).  But if you are going to have an unknown number of `length` values, then you will need to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(length) 
                    from items
                    group by length
                    order by length
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT type, color, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select type, color, length, price
              from items
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(price)
                for length in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
            order by type'

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/20639/16)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query to PIVOT this table. But you should know `Length` values to define rows if you don't know them then you [need to use dynamic query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query).

```
SELECT Type,Color,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Length=1 THEN price END) as [1],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Length=1.5 THEN price END) as [1.5],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Length=2 THEN price END) as [2],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Length=3 THEN price END) as [3],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Length=4 THEN price END) as [4]

FROM items
GROUP BY Type,Color
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/20639/10)</kbd>